# Finding the max date from an array of dates using javascript

Tags: javascript

There are two date fields namely 'Date 1' and 'Date 2'. On clicking the button 'Check', the maximum of the two dates need to be printed in the 'Max Date' field. So how to print the max date from a set of dates. I have tried pushing the date values into an array and finding out the max, but something seems wrong. Below is the HTML and javascript code.

```js
function checkMaxDate() {
    var dateArray = [];
    var date1 = dateArray.push(document.getElementById('date1').value);
    var date2 = dateArray.push(document.getElementById('date2').value);
    var maxDate = Math.max.apply(Math, dateArray);
    document.getElementById('maxdate').value = maxDate;
}
```

```html
Date 1: <input type="date" id="date1" />
Date 2: <input type="date" id="date2" />
Max Date: <input type="date" id="maxdate" />
<button type="button" onclick="checkMaxDate()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Your values will be strings, not dates. Does the user enter the dates themself? If so how do you know which format they will use?

Comment: Yes the  user would enter the dates. The format is dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping `document.getElementById('date1').value` in `new Date().getTime()` .

Also `input type="date"` accepts value as `yyyy-mm-dd` ; try using `.toJSON()` , `String.prototype.slice()` to set date properly for `#maxdate` as `yyyy-mm-dd` from value returned as `maxDate`

```js
function checkMaxDate() {
  var dateArray = [];
  var date1 = dateArray.push(new Date(document.getElementById('date1').value).getTime());
  var date2 = dateArray.push(new Date(document.getElementById('date2').value).getTime());
  var maxDate = Math.max.apply(Math, dateArray);
  document.getElementById('maxdate').value = new Date(maxDate).toJSON().slice(0, 10);
}
```

```html
Date 1:
<input type="date" id="date1" />Date 2:
<input type="date" id="date2" />Max Date:
<input type="date" id="maxdate" />
<button type="button" onclick="checkMaxDate()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Try applying the function inside a newDate, and `null` instead of `Math`. You should also `new Date(pushedArrayElement)` to be a Date object, and not push `Strings` into the date array.

`var maxDate= new Date(Math.max.apply(null,dateArray));`

Note that there's cause for error because it's not guaranteed that the user input will be a legal date format.

Comment: What about the fact that the 2 inputs are strings, not dates?

Comment: @SterlingArcher `input type="date"` accepts setting date as `yyyy-mm-dd` , not as value of `new Date()`

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot.